# Scheduling a job multiple times

Tags: parse-platform

I wrote a background job that accepts some parameters, and I scheduled it to run periodically. I now want to schedule it with a different parameter set, but the parse.com console says I have no background jobs.

I've worked around the problem adding the same job multiple times with slightly different names, but this solution is far from ideal. There should be a way to schedule a job with multiple parameter set and different schedules.

Is there a way to schedule the same job multiple times?

Comment: I believe that a you can only schedule a job to run at one specific time

Comment: You can set [repeat](http://blog.parse.com/2013/09/04/introducing-background-jobs/) too

Comment: I meant that you can't get it to run at 12 am, 12:30 am, and 2am.